# Output .less as .css when EnableOptimizations=false

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, less, bundling-and-minification, dotless

I have the following ASP.NET MVC Bundle:

```
var lessBundle = new Bundle("~/bundles/common.css");

lessBundle.Include("~/CSS/Header.less",
                   "~/CSS/Footer.less");

lessBundle.Transforms.Add(new LessTransform());

bundles.Add(lessBundle);
```

When `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true` this is bundled together, as expected, and outputed as:

```
<link href="/bundles/common.css?v=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

When `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false` this is outputted as:

```
<link href="/CSS/Header.less" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/CSS/Footer.less" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Is there a way of changing this so that the file extensions appear as `.css` rather than `.less`?

Therefore:

```
<link href="/CSS/Header.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/CSS/Footer.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: Hey Curt, are you still looking for an answer to this question?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can change the file extensions when `EnableOptimizations` is set to `false` as stated by the [documentation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)...

> Unless EnableOptimizations is true or the debug attribute in the compilation Element  in the Web.config file is set to false, files will not be bundled or minified. Additionally, the .min version of files will not be used,  the full debug versions will be selected. EnableOptimizations  overrides the debug attribute in the compilation Element  in the Web.config file

That means that the compilation mode and the `EnableOptimizations` property will define whether these resources will get bundled and minified. In your case, when you set `EnableOptimizations` to `false` the Optimization Engine will not do any transformation to these resources and render them exactly what you defined them here...

```
lessBundle.Include("~/CSS/Header.less",
               "~/CSS/Footer.less");
```

hence the output html (with the help of razor) will render the following links...

```
<link href="/CSS/Header.less" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/CSS/Footer.less" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

That's the default behaviour, if you want to do nothing fancy, there's nothing stopping you from having a peek at the [asp.net stack](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/)...which is thanksfully open source and implement your desired behaviour

### Update

Actually the Optimization Framework's Source it's a separate extension that you can find [here](http://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/)